# Symfony blank page instead of Twig Error Page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Doing this in Symfony Controller gives me a nice Twig Error Page:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');
```

But doing this only gives a blank page and error is logged to dev.log:

```
$foo = null;
$foo->bar();
```

In app_dev.php I enabled Debugging:

```
Debug::enable();
```

How could I get an Error page for both cases? And how could I get this error page even in production?

In production (app.php) I use:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ExceptionHandler::register();
ErrorHandler::register();
```

Comment: I solved the latter case using an error page in Nginx (Proxy in front of my Apache)